# jQuery multiple textareas with different ids

Tags: jquery

I have a page that contains multiple textarea elements.  These textareas and the IDs are generated dynamically when originally rendered to the screen.

I know that the selector for the textarea have to be identical.

I can loop through my original data that I used to generate the elements to create a variable that contains the actual id of the textarea.  But when I tried to do that I was getting an error.

This was my attempt:

```
for (i=0;i<=#.myglobals.result.length-1;i++){
var itemName = $.myglobals.result[i].id;
alert($('textarea#'+itemName).val());
}
```

What I ultimately want is to capture if the textarea has information in it and display
the information if it does.

Please let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
$("textarea").each( 
    function(idx, item) { 
        var value = $(item).val();
        if (value) alert(value);
    } 
);
```

Comment: Both answers worked, however, this one did what I needed it to do!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$("textarea").each( function() { alert($(this).attr("id")); } );
```

This finds all textareas on the screen and shows their id in a popup.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code, hope this will help.

```
var thought = '';
jQuery("textarea.feedback_msg").each(function() {
    thought += $(this).val();
});
```